# why changing the font in Textclip may not work?

Tags: python, moviepy

There is a function that adds text to a video clip. But when you specify the font style parameter, it does not change. What could be the problem?

Cod:

```
vid = VideoFileClip(name_video)
text1 = TextClip(text_for_video,  fontsize=size, font='Courier', color=color)
txt_clip = text1.set_pos(("right", "top"), relative=True).set_duration(text_end_time-text_start_time)

text2 = TextClip(text_for_video, fontsize=size, font='TimesNewRoman', color=color)
txt_clip_2 = text2.set_pos(("right", "top"), relative=True).set_duration(5)
video = CompositeVideoClip([vid, txt_clip.set_start(text_start_time), txt_clip_2.set_start(10)])
video.write_videofile('video_res.mp4', codec='libx264')
```

Answer (score 4):

May be the font name would be different just check the font available using the code

```
from moviepy.editor import TextClip
        print ( TextClip.list("font") )
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30504714)